# How do I creates arrays from a series of <span>

Tags: jquery, css

How do I make an array from a series of `<span>` in a specific `<div>` when clicking `btn` ?

```
<div class="btn">Make Arrays<div>

<div class="Wrapper">
  <div class="some elements"></div>
  <div class="Arrays">
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter value">
    <div>some stuff</div>
    <span>123.23</span>
    <span>52</span>
    <span>728.4</span>
    <span>52</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Wrapper">
  <div class="some elements"></div>
  <div class="Arrays">
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter value">
    <div>some stuff</div>
    <span>10.8</span>
    <span>28.7</span>
  </div>
</div> ...
```

Output
`var Array1 = ['123.23', '52', '728.4', '52']`
`var Array2 = ['10.8', '28.1']` ...

The thing is, I will not know how many `class="Arrays"` will be because it is a dynamic elements. so maybe there should be a way of indexing it by adding dummy classes like 'Array1', 'Array2' into 'class="Arrays"'

So, basically, how do I index each `<Arrays>` div and make an array out of its `<span>`

Many Thanks~~~ =)

Comment: How about making array of arrays?

Comment: You can make an array of arrays, that's the best way for you.

Comment: How is the data being put in there in the first place? Is it being manually coded or programmably generated? If it's being generated then there may be a better way to do this.

Comment: @kojow7 it is being entered by the user from `<input>` then wrapped in `<span>`. the thing user can create or delete each `Wrapper` freely and I will never know how many it will have

Comment: @Abinthaha  Arrays of Arrays!!!? what is that?

Comment: @fen1x Arrays of Arrays!!!? what is that?

Comment: Like, you can create an array inside a parent array. It will be like nesting arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will return array of arrays.

```js
function getArray() {
  const arr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.Arrays'))
    .map(a => Array.from(a.querySelectorAll('span')).map(span => span.textContent));

  console.log(arr)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getArray()">getArray</button>

<div class="btn">Make Arrays
  <div>

    <div class="Wrapper">
      <div class="some elements"></div>
      <div class="Arrays">
        <input type="text" placeholder="enter value">
        <div>some stuff</div>
        <span>123.23</span>
        <span>52</span>
        <span>728.4</span>
        <span>52</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Wrapper">
      <div class="some elements"></div>
      <div class="Arrays">
        <input type="text" placeholder="enter value">
        <div>some stuff</div>
        <span>10.8</span>
        <span>28.7</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! It works like a charm, and it is in pure JavaScript too~~!!!

Answer (score 1):

This works to get your arrays from the values in the spans. It's a simple solution using jQuery's each.

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var arrs = [];
    $('.Arrays').each(function(i,el){
        temp = [];
        $('span', $(el)).each(function(i2,el2){
            temp.push($(el2).text());
        });
        arrs.push(temp);
    });
    console.log(arrs);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for writing in! Btw, what is `$(el)` ?

Comment: What, no love? See the docs on how to use each: https://api.jquery.com/each/ . i is the index of the element, and el is the element.

Comment: *Gives you a hug and a beer~~~ Oh, very much appreciated for the info man~~~ Cheers~~~

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the snippet. In the `onClick` method, the values in the span will be retrieved and pushed into a parentArray called `arr`. Also, the childArray formed is appending to a list.

In the example, I used to give classes for each `span` and thereby retrieving the value using those class names. In another method, you can loop through each of the `span` in the container and push those values into the childArray itself.

```js
var arr = [];
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  var newArr = [];
  $('.Arrays').each(function(index, el) {
    $(el).find('span').each(function(ind, spanEl) {
      var value = $(spanEl).html();
      newArr.push(value);
    })
  })
  
  arr.push(newArr)
  
  $('.list').append('<li>'+newArr+'</li>')
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="Wrapper">
  <div class="some elements"></div>
  <div class="Arrays">
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter value">
    <div>some stuff</div>
    <span class="one">123.23</span>
    <span class="two">52</span>
    <span class="three">728.4</span>
    <span class="four">52</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Wrapper">
  <div class="some elements"></div>
  <div class="Arrays">
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter value">
    <div>some stuff</div>
    <span>10.8</span>
    <span>28.7</span>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn">Make Arrays</button>

<h4>List</h4>
<ul class="list">
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for writing in! But it only works on the first Wrapper div only right?

Comment: Yes, and there will be multiple wrapper as it is a dynamic content~~~